# javascript canvas: chrome touch screen not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas, touchscreen

I have a project created with canvas. This project works fine on every browser on my iMac (Safari, Chrome, Opera, IE, Mozilla). For this I have created a normal click function:

```
$('#canvas').click(function(e) {}
```

When opening this project on a Windows7 SmartBoard (with Multisync s521-p nec) it also works fine, except at Chrome, you cannot touch it. If you click with the mouse on the SmartBoard, that is not a problem at all, but you just cannot touch it with the fingers. Since my project will just be used on this SmartBoard, and preferable at Chrome I really need to fix this, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript touch events instead of *click*:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events#Setting_up_the_event_handlers

*click* is a mouse operation and because the device has "mouse" it is reserved for it.